# django core exceptions ImproperlyConfigured:

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, environment-variables, virtualenv, django-settings

I had my django up and running last night at around midnight, everything was kawa when i closed but in the morning when i open my pc i get django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: error

!error

`Note that only Django core commands are listed as settings are not properly configured (error: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.).`

I tried closing the VScode and Terminal, reopened them, started virtualenvironment again but the error persists

`\env\Scripts\python.exe: No module named django`

I have django installed on the virtudal env as well as set as a global environment variable
thanks in advance

I expected python to get django installed on the virtual environment

Comment: Apparently you have not installed Django on the virtualenv. Try `\env\scripts\python.exe -m pip freeze` and confirm if Django is listed.

Comment: I think i get it, while i was working before closing i installed another virtual env in project folder .. so the project was using that virtual env.. i manually deleted it now it's working

Comment: OperationalError at /admin/thena_users/blog/21/change/
(1054, "Unknown column 'users.role_id' in 'field list'")
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/thena_users/blog/21/change/
Django Version: 4.1.1
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value: 
(1054, "Unknown column 'users.role_id' in 'field list'")

Comment: Thats the error i get